# how to make dynamic each function name of controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I want to dynamic function name of controller in codeigniter like:

```
$functionName = 'profile'; 

function $functionName(){
------
-----
-----
}
```

Actually I want to change url http://website/manage/viewprfile/Username to  http://website/manage/profile/Username  and that url is used in whole website.

Comment: on what basis, you will call the function??

Answer (score 1):

jus add this routes in application/config/routes.php

```
$route['manage'] = 'manage/index';
$route['manage/(:any)'] = 'manage/$1';
```

now u can access to manage/profile/username, manage/somethingelse

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is to write route rules in following way`$route['manage/prfile '] = 'manage/viewprfile';`
this will change your URL to specific that you want.
Other way is to create a hook for rewriting your URL.

Comment: you need to do this in file application/routes.php